Separation of variables issue
I'm currently trying to solve the following PDE -
$$ \partial_{t}u(x,t) - \partial_{xx}u(x,t) = 0 \quad 0<x<2, t>0 $$
$$ u(0,t) = 1 \quad u(2,t) = 3 \quad t \geq 0 $$
$$ u(x,0) = x^2 - x + 1 \quad 0 \leq x \leq 2$$
Separating $u(x,t) = v(x)w(t)$ and plugging it inside the equation + using the boundary conditions, I arrive at the equation
$$ v''(x) = \lambda v(x) $$
$$ v(0) = 1, v(2) = 3 $$
Now, if $\lambda = 0$, the solution would be $v(x) = x+1$. I admit that now I'm a bit confused as to how to continue with the example here. I did the general solution of the form first
$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_{k} sin\left(\frac{k\pi x}{2}\right) e^\left(-\frac{k^2 \pi^2 t}{4}\right) $$
and then decided to look at it from the start but I'm not entirely sure how to follow up. Thank you for any tips.

Oooh you have to split the equation into two parts. Thank you a lot, that does make a lot more sense.
